# receive HTML from server in ajax call and load page with that HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on `CodeIgniter` and `AJAX`. What I am trying to do that I have a datatable which contains list of employee. On button click I get the `ID` of employee and send it to my controller in which I get all the necessary details from DB of that specific employee. I have already done this.
The issue I am facing is that how can I redirect to `viewEmployeeProfile` page after successful ajax call with that specific Employee Detail.

Here is my code:

**JS**

```
$('#viewAllEmployeeTable tbody').on('click', '.viewEmployeeDetail', function() {
    var data = viewAllEmployeeTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    employeeID = data.employeeID;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ackamarackus/employee/viewEmployeeProfile",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "employeeID": employeeID
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            //console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

**viewEmployeeProfile Function**

```
public function viewEmployeeProfile() {
    $employeeID =  $this->input->post('employeeID');
    $data['employeeBasicDetails'] = $this -> getemployeeBasicDetailsFromDatabase($employeeID);
    $data['employeeDepartmentalDeails'] = $this -> getemployeeDepartmentalDeailsFromDatabase($employeeID);
    $data['employeeSalaryDetails'] = $this -> getemployeeSalaryDetailsFromDatabase($employeeID);
    $data['employeeEducationDetails'] = $this -> getemployeeEducationDetailsFromDatabase($employeeID);
    $data['employeeJobHistoryDetails'] = $this -> getemployeeJobHistoryDetailsFromDatabase($employeeID);
    $data['employeeTrainingDetails'] = $this -> getemployeeTrainingDetailsFromDatabase($employeeID);
    $data['header'] = 'template/header';
    $data['sidebar'] = 'template/sidebar';
    $data['main_content'] = 'viewEmployeeProfile';
    $data['footer'] = 'template/footer';

    echo $this -> load -> view('template/template', $data, TRUE);
}
```

**template/template view**

```
//This view is generic and implements templating 
$this->load->view($header);
$this->load->view($sidebar);
$this->load->view($main_content);
$this->load->view($footer);
```

after the request `console.log(data)`; gives me the HTML of `viewEmployeeProfile view` 
I have also tried to echo the content from $data array like `print_r($employeeBasicDetails);` and it gives me the correct information. BUT I don't know how to load that view with the HTML received from ajax call ?

Any idea how to do this or is there any good hack for this  solution, may be I am doing it all wrong. Any input in this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Having to make a database call *per field* seems extraordinarily wasteful and inefficient. Why can't you fetch the record in one shot and extract the fields you're interested in? I'd wager this is the result of writing a home-brew ORM without understanding how they're supposed to operate.  Have a look at  [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) before re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Using a proper ORM this should be as easy as 1. Fetch record. 2. Dump fields as JSON.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the nice idea, BUT I will focus on it later. Your answer is not what I asked in my question

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't do things the Codeigniter way instead of carving your own path. This code makes no sense. If you just want to redirect, manipulate `window.location` in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This line of your ajax call specifies the type of data to expect in return from the server. If you are outputting HTML you need to change it as currently you are telling the ajax request to expect json in return

```
dataType: "json"
```

To insert it into your page you just need to specify where you want it. Create an empty span/div whatever and give it an id, then in your success callback you can insert the returned data into that element on your page. Say your div id was employee then you add the following to your success callback:

```
$('#employee').html(data);
```